# How to remove items in deep array of objects?

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have the following array of objects:

```
[
   { id: "1", categories: [ { category_id: "1"}, { category_id: "2"} ],
   { id: "2", categories: [ { category_id: "2"}, { category_id: "3"} ],
   { id: "3", categories: [ { category_id: "1"}, { category_id: "5"} ],
]
```

I want remove all the items which doesn't have as `category_id` those not included in this array of references: `1, 4, 5`.

So the expected output should be: `1, 3`, because the id 2 doesn't have any category id contained in teh references array.

I wrote this code:

```
items.filter(obj => !references.includes(obj.categories.category_id));
```

but this will return the same items

Expected result:

```
[
   { id: "1", categories: [ { category_id: "1"}, { category_id: "2"} ],
   { id: "3", categories: [ { category_id: "1"}, { category_id: "5"} ],
]
```

Comment: please add the result in literal notation.

Comment: I don't understand what your desired result looks like.

Comment: @connexo check update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and the value with [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

```js
var array = [{ id: "1", categories: [{ category_id: "1" }, { category_id: "2" }] }, { id: "2", categories: [{ category_id: "2" }, { category_id: "3" }] }, { id: "3", categories: [{ category_id: "1" }, { category_id: "5" }] }],
    keep = ["1", "4", "5"],
    result = array.filter(({ categories }) => 
        categories.some(({ category_id }) => keep.includes(category_id)));
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: why +category_id?

Comment: the value is a string, the values of keeping values are numbers. to convert a string to a number, you could use an [unary plus `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus) - or take strings as well.

Answer (score 1):

`obj.categories` is an array, you have to iterate it in some way:

```
items.filter(obj => obj.categories.every(category => !references.includes(category.category_id)));
```

Comment: get same result though :\

Answer (score 0):

Here you have another approach that uses [Array::findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)

```js
const input = [
   {id: "1", categories: [{category_id: "1"}, {category_id: "2"}]},
   {id: "2", categories: [{category_id: "2"}, {category_id: "3"}]},
   {id: "3", categories: [{category_id: "1"}, {category_id: "5"}]},
];

const references = [1, 4, 5];

let res = input.filter(
    y => y.categories.findIndex(x => references.includes(Number(x.category_id))) >= 0
);

console.log(res);
```